# Calculate polygon area using Polylines

Tags: android, area, geo, polyline

I need to calculate a polygon area on my mapView. I studied this case, and de Polylines shows the best way to make a area, with the points that the user was informed. But I didn't find the way to calculate his area! Can anyone help me please? Or suggest other alternative to draw polygons and calculate area/perimeter in android application.

Answer (score 0):

1. convert lat/lon points to cartesian space
2. Use area of polygon formula you easily find in wiki.

ad 1) if polygons diameter are not more than some 10s of kilomters an EquiRectangular Projection makes sense and is very simple, using the center of the polygon as center of transofrmation (cos (centerLatitude)).
Otherwise task 1 is complex.